# Mysql Enum column type select all values

Tags: mysql

I have Enum column with 2 values in it.Yes and No, `Col('Yes','No')`

Now I have a one functionality where in I have use this column and pull rows  with both yes and no values,

Now when I do something like `col = ('Yes' OR 'No')`

I dont get any records, how do I pull all rows from that has all values of enum column.I need rows that has both yes and no values.

This column is part of one of my large query so refactoring the column from enum to varchar does solve the problem ? But I am curious to know as how to select all values for enum? I tried many ways,but I always null results.

Comment: If you want all of them, do not include `col` in the `WHERE` clause at all. It won't be filtered.

Comment: But anway, the correct syntax would be `col = 'Yes' OR col = 'No'` or using `IN()` as `col IN('Yes', 'No')`

Comment: ah Michael,You made my day.Thanks a lot.I never thought of going via IN.I will explore that.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`.

```
SELECT blah blah blah FROM blah WHERE col IN ('Yes','No')
```

Comment: I will use IN Kolink.Thanks